# What Am I? - A Word Riddle no. 2

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Many have me, yet none own me,
>
> though I am never truly eliminated,
>
> I am rid of through knowledge.
>
> More widespread the more things are known,
>
> What am I?

Comment: "I am ridden of through knowledge," is not a typo, you get rid of it through knowledge.

Comment: Ridden does not mean "got rid of". It's the past participle of ride (as in riding a horse).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will change that to be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are...

> Doubt.

Many have me, yet none own me,

> It is common to have doubts, but the nature of being unsure means you can't even be sure of your doubt.

though I am never truly eliminated,

> No one is omniscient; even the best-accepted scientific theories in the world can change if new evidence arises, and no one can truly know that none ever will.

I am ridden of through knowledge.

> The more you learn, the more sure you are.

More widespread the more things are known,

> Every new fact/discovery is another chance for someone to be unsure about it.

Comment: Thank you for answering, and welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

Comment: I was thinking more of along the lines of 'questions' but this answer is close enough/has the same meaning, so I would say that it is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> ignorance

Many have me, yet none own me,

> You can have ignorance but no one can own ignorance.

though I am never truly eliminated,

> You can't eliminate all ignorance in the world.

I am ridden of through knowledge.

> Once you know something, you're no longer ignorant of it.

More widespread the more things are known,

> The more things that are known, the more things there are to be ignorant of.

Comment: Not quite, but that could also be a decent answer, if the wording of the riddle was slightly altered.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are a

> prejudice?

Many have me, yet none own me,

> Many people have prejudices but they don't own them.

though I am never truly eliminated,

> It may be hard to overcome a prejudice, especially an old one...

I am ridden of through knowledge.

> ...but the more you know the less you assume.

More widespread the more things are known,

> There are more prejudices the more things you know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a ...

> rumour?

**Explanation**

Many have me, yet none own me,

> Many people have rumours, but no single person actually "owns" a rumour

though I am never truly eliminated,

> Despite clarifications, rumours cannot be 100% eliminated

I am ridden of through knowledge.

> When awareness is available, rumours are set to rest

More widespread the more things are known,

> The more widespread rumours are, the wilder they get (sometimes they change completely from the original message)

What am I?

Comment: That's close, but not quite. I'll add a hint soon.